# importing csv file with django-adaptors

Tags: python, django, csv, django-adaptors

I'm trying to import csv file with [django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org), unfortunately i have an error in this process.

I created my model and CSV class like this:

```
class depts(models.Model):
    iddepts = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CustomerID = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    CustomerName = models.CharField(max_length=750, default='none', null=False)
    InvoiceID = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, default=0, null=False)
    Currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='EUR', null=False)
    CurrencyRate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2) 
    PriceWithoutVAT = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    PriceWithVAT = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    VAT = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    CustomerVATID = models.CharField(max_length=35, default='000-000-000-000', null=False)
    CustomerAddress = models.CharField(max_length=750, default='none', null=False)
    InvoiceBranch = models.IntegerField(max_length=3, default='000', null=False)
    InvoiceVATType = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, default='1', null=False)
    InvoiceDateCreate = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    InvoiceDateDue = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    InvoiceCodeVAT = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='none', null=False)
    PriceWithoutVATStandard = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    PriceWithVATStandard = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    VATStandard = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    AccountVAT = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='none', null=False)
    AccountPriceWithoutVAT = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='none', null=False)
    AccountPriceWithVAT = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='none', null=False)
    class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Invoice"
            verbose_name_plural = "Invoices"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.InvoiceID        
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.InvoiceID
class MyCsvModel(CsvDbModel):
    class Meta:
          dbModel = depts
          delimiter = ";"
          has_header = True
```

my csv file looks like this:

```
CustomerID;CustomerName;InvoiceID;Currency;CurrencyRate;PriceWithoutVAT;PriceWithVAT;VAT;CustomerVATID;CustomerAddress;InvoiceBranch;InvoiceVATType;InvoiceDateCreate;InvoiceDateDue;InvoiceCodeVAT;PriceWithoutVATStandard;PriceWithVATStandard;VATStandard;AccountVAT;AccountPriceWithoutVAT;AccountPriceWithVAT
73269;Good CO;131002919;EUR;1;141.12;173.58;32.46;666-666-11-11;Good street 123;002;1;2013-04-15;2013-04-22;21% ;141.12;173.58;32.46;111-111;111-111-111;111-111-11111
```

You can see that i have extra Field im model "iddepts" which is primary key, exluding it in MyCsvModel dosent slove problem. i have still error on import_data.

```
>>>from app.models import MyCsvModel
>>>my_csv_list = MyCsvModel.import_data(data = open("file.csv"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/adaptor/model.py", line 197, in import_data
return importer.import_data(data)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adaptor/model.py", line 467, in import_data
self.process_line(data, line, lines, line_number, self.csvModel)
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/adaptor/model.py", line 487, in process_line
raise CsvDataException(line_number, error="Number of fields invalid")
CsvDataException: Line 2: Number of fields invalid
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CsvDbModel means your django model fields and CSV columns match. Your CSV data lacks a column for iddepts.

Therefore you need to create a django-adaptors CsvModel. And you need to tell DateField how a date is formatted. In your CSV file:

> '%Y-%m-%d'

django-adaptors [defaults it to](https://github.com/anthony-tresontani/django-adaptors/blob/master/adaptor/fields.py#L123):

> '%d/%m/%Y'

Set up this model. If field names of your Csv model does not match the field names of your django model, you can [manage this with the match keyword](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#django-model)

```
from adaptor.model import CsvModel
from adaptor.fields import CharField, IntegerField, DecimalField, DateField

from application.models import depts      

class DeptsCsvModel(CsvModel):

    CustomerID = IntegerField()
    CustomerName = CharField()
    InvoiceID = IntegerField()
    Currency = CharField()
    CurrencyRate = DecimalField() 
    PriceWithoutVAT = DecimalField()
    PriceWithVAT = DecimalField()
    VAT = DecimalField()
    CustomerVATID = CharField()
    CustomerAddress = CharField()
    InvoiceBranch = IntegerField()
    InvoiceVATType = IntegerField()
    InvoiceDateCreate = DateField(**{'format':'%Y-%m-%d'})
    InvoiceDateDue = DateField(**{'format':'%Y-%m-%d'})
    InvoiceCodeVAT = CharField()
    PriceWithoutVATStandard = DecimalField()
    PriceWithVATStandard = DecimalField()
    VATStandard = DecimalField()
    AccountVAT = CharField()
    AccountPriceWithoutVAT = CharField()
    AccountPriceWithVAT = CharField()

    class Meta:
        dbModel = depts
        delimiter = ";"
        has_header = True
```

Using this model you can import CSV file using django shell. I did successfully import your CSV data into SQL database table.

```
gottfried@lubuntu-virtual-machine:~/virtualenvs/django-adaptors/soquestion/application$ ../../bin/python ../manage.py shell
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:12:53) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from application.adaptors import DeptsCsvModel
>>> DeptsCsvModel.import_data(data = open('data.csv'))
[<application.adaptors.DeptsCsvModel object at 0x93efa8c>]
```

Customization option: You can even create custom fields matching date formats in your CSV data.

```
class DeptsDateField(DateField):
    "encapsulate specific data properties into a class for use with django-adaptors CsvModel fields"

    def __init__(self):
        super(DeptsDateField, self).__init__(**{'format':'%Y-%m-%d'})

class DeptsCsvModel(CsvModel):

    CustomerID = IntegerField()
    CustomerName = CharField()
    InvoiceID = IntegerField()
    Currency = CharField()
    CurrencyRate = DecimalField() 
    PriceWithoutVAT = DecimalField()
    PriceWithVAT = DecimalField()
    VAT = DecimalField()
    CustomerVATID = CharField()
    CustomerAddress = CharField()
    InvoiceBranch = IntegerField()
    InvoiceVATType = IntegerField()
    InvoiceDateCreate = DeptsDateField
    InvoiceDateDue = DeptsDateField
    InvoiceCodeVAT = CharField()
    PriceWithoutVATStandard = DecimalField()
    PriceWithVATStandard = DecimalField()
    VATStandard = DecimalField()
    AccountVAT = CharField()
    AccountPriceWithoutVAT = CharField()
    AccountPriceWithVAT = CharField()

    class Meta:
        dbModel = depts
        delimiter = ";"
        has_header = True
```

Comment: i try your solution and now import works, but datefield are not correct,every record has present date.

Comment: This is because your Django DateFields are like models.DateField(auto_now=True). This throws away any value provided by using django-adaptors. Got it from the docs. I suggest using a django model ONLY for CSV import not using auto_now for DateFields and the one you provided in question for every other application context.

Comment: when I insert this, it shows error and tells "No module named 'application'"- what can I do, if you could tell me

Comment: Unless you maintain an old Django installation, I would recommend to change the framework to import CSV data into Django. django-adaptors is rather old and unmaintained, Django has changed as well. Why invest time in a zombie project like django-adaptors?

Comment: @SaschaGottfried- Not sure if I may ask it here - was exploring various options of importing legacy data into Django models. Without a definitive source, I came across django-adaptors and thought it would suit my purpose. However seeing your comment I am now not so sure. If possible, could you direct me to a possible solution (I am using Django ver. 2.0.6 on python 3.6). Thanks.